# Deleting all files with filenames matching a pattern and size below a certain limit

Tags: bash

I need to delete all files with a `.avi` expansion and whose size is below **100MB**. I have a large collection of video files and I need to delete the short ones to free up some space. How do I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `find` command:

```
find /path/to/ -name '*.avi' -type f -size -100M -delete
```

Details:

- `/path/to/`

  This tells find to look for files in the `/path/to/` directory and all its subdirectories.  If you want to start from the current directory, use `.` instead.
- `-name '*.avi'`

  This tells `find` to only look for files whose names end in `.avi`
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` to only look for regular files.  This excludes directories, pipes, sockets, etc.
- `-size -100M`

  This tells `find` to only look for files smaller than 100MB.  If you wanted to delete files larger than 100MB, then use `+100M` instead.
- `-delete`

  This tells `find` to delete the files matching the above criteria.

For safety, the first time you try this command, leave off the `-delete`.  This will return a list of files found:

```
    find /path/to/ -name '*.avi' -type f -size -100M
```

If the files found are the ones that you want to delete, then add back `-delete`.

#### Searching only the current directory and *not* its subdirectories

To limit recursion find into subdirectories, use the `-maxdepth` option:

```
find /path/to/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.avi' -type f -size -100M -delete
```

To perform the above on the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.avi' -type f -size -100M -delete
```

Comment: How do I do if I want it to look only in the current directory and not look recursively into the subdirectories ?

Comment: @Chintan That can be done with `-maxdepth`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Minimal typo on bullet #3: `'type f`, should be `-type f`. :)